# Database Schema Name for General Database Tables

Tags: sql-server, database

When designing databases, I have been following the conventions of the Microsoft AdventureWorks sample database. They use schemas to logically separate groups of tables, e.g. `Person`, `Production` or `Sales`. It makes a lot of sense from a security point of view as well as from an organizational pov.

However, I have some tables that are used in multiple schemas. For example, a `Country` table that contains all countries. It wouldn't make sense to assign a sepecific schema to it, e.g. `Person.Country` or `Production.Country` as it is used in tables of different schemas.

Therefore, which schema do I assign it to?

Comment: `Shared.Country`, `Shared.Products` (as they appear in Production and Sales)?

Comment: Is that best practice? @HardCode

Comment: it's more opinion based. There really is no best practice for exact naming. Best practice could be, however, to put all shared tables in the same schema, not the actual schema name.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "dbo" schema, its the default schema for sql-server and many others.

Comment: Or maybe `Location.Country` and `Location.Address`?